# Visual Studio, Android: Find out, which Framework is neccessary for Nuget-packages

Tags: android, visual-studio, nuget

I am in bit of a tumble here. I am wanting to move away from admob. I read the Facebook Ads SDK is just "as" good, if not better.

So, for that I am working with Visual Studio, I need to download the SDK via the Nuget-console. But as soon as I am trying install the Facebook SDK Version 6.0.10. it gives me the error that (translated from german):

```
"The package "Facebook 6.0.10" could not be installed. You are trying to install this package into a project, that references "MonoAndroid, Version = v8.0". The Package however does not include any assembly reference or data that would be compatable with this framework."
```

I am however able to install the Facebook Version JUST before that (5.4.1) but I need the newer one.

What's also weired is the fact, that I am running the newest and second newest frameworks and tried both but nothing from the 6+ range of Facebook SDKs will install.

However, my question: How can I find out, which framework is neccissary in order to install any nuget package? I cannot download and try them all, that would be insane - there must be a better way, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I find out, which framework is necessary in order to install any nuget package? I cannot download and try them all, that would be insane - there must be a better way, right?

To find out which framework is necessary when installing any nuget package, The only way I know is to look inside the NuGet package itself.

I use the [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) to see the framework it supports, you can get it from Microsoft store.

For example, I downloaded the package Facebook 6.0.10 from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/6.0.10) manually and open it with nuget package explorer:

[image]

Then we could to know the package Facebook 6.0.10 supports:

```
  - net35-client (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Client)
  - net40-client (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - sl4-wp71 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71)
  - sl5 (Silverlight,Version=v5.0)
  - winrt (WinRT,Version=v0.0)
```

That is the reason why you got the error "The package "Facebook 6.0.10" could not be installed. You are trying to install this package into a project, that references "**MonoAndroid, Version = v8.0**", MonoAndroid, Version = v8.0 is not in the support list for the package `Facebook 6.0.10`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it helps a ton.but what i dont understand: this looks like I would need, for instance, framework version 4.0 to install version 6.0.10, right? BUT: this framework version is like ULTRA outdated, isnt it? also: the fb version 5xxx works on framework 7xx? so why would the newer versions need the older frameworks?!?

Comment: In generally, the target framework is backward compatible, that means you could install a framework version 4.0 dll assembly to the project which target framework is 6.0, but the reverse is not possible, you could not install a framework version 6.0 dll assembly to the project which target framework is 4.0.

Comment: Aagin, the nuget package which have older frameworks is used for those project which target older frameworks, otherwise, those older frameworks projects could not install the newer version assembly.

Comment: Okay, but then why did my target framework (8.0) not work with facebook sdk when it is supposed to be backwards compatible?

Comment: NO! It is **MonoAndroid 8.0**, not .net framework 8.0! Your target framework `MonoAndroid 8.0` should compatible `MonoAndroid 8.0` and below assembly, which is not supported by `Facebook 6.0.10` (There is no MonoAndroid under the support list.). In other words, this package Facebook not support Android project.

Comment: so, i can never install the package, no matter what i do?

Comment: For the Android project, the answer is yes :(. Hope this answer help you.